# Symbolizing problem

Tags: notation

$AB$ with a stripe above each letter symbolizes a vector or the distance from one point to another?

Remind me of that?

Thank you very much

Comment: An arrow above the pair ($\overrightarrow{AB}$) would mean a vector. I'm not sure what a "stripe above each letter" looks like. If it's $\bar{A}\bar{B}$ the meaning may depend on the context.

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{AB}$?